# Android App Name Doesnt Get Displayed on toolbar

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-launcher, main-activity

in my news app which has a navigation drawer,doesnt display the activity/app name in the toolbar,all other activity refer the app name from the Strings.xml and display respectivly in their toolbar,but the main activity which starts from the launcher just display a blank toolbar with hamburger icon,here is my manifest.please help me to fix the problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:name=".app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NewsInDetailActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MalayalamewsActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MalayalamNewsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HindiNewsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".KannadaNews"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NewsDetails"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_news_details"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you show the .xml of the MainActivity how you add the toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is a hint which should get you going, you should have something like this in your `MainActivity.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:minHeight="100dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then in the `MainActivity.java` you should set the Toolbar like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if(toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title!");
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.